# Reload Div Data Last updates

Tags: php, jquery, html, reload

I have div with name with test name and contents is something.

I want add text link and when user on click on the link Contents update without refresh page every article call.php file for reload, but I want call DIV id (test) for example when I edit my file and something text to something2 and after save file click on href tag text show something2 in page without refresh page.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO.What have you tried till now?

Comment: You probably need AJAX for this. For reference: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.ASP